# Implementing Java interface in Scala results in incompatible type map

Tags: java, scala, interface, scala-java-interop

I have a Java interface that I want to implement in Scala. The interface contains the following method-declaration:

```
 List<Map<String, Object>> xyz(Map<String, Object> var1, Map<String, Object> var2);
```

My Scala implementation is:

```
override def testComponent( input: java.util.Map[String, Object], metadata: java.util.Map[String, Object] )
  {

    val list: util.List[Map[String, AnyRef]] = new util.ArrayList[Map[String, AnyRef]]

     return list
  }
```

ERROR : overriding method xyz in trait ITester of type (x$1: java.util.Map[String,Object], x$2: java.util.Map[String,Object])java.util.List[java.util.Map[String,Object]];
method testComponent has incompatible type
override def testComponent( input: java.util.Map[String, Object], metadata: java.util.Map[String, Object] )

I don't know what exactly the issue is.

Comment: Can you share the whole code, there's some missing stuff that makes your question hard to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of `testComponent` has type `Unit` because it's defined using the (deprecated in recent versions of Scala) procedure syntax of `def name(args) { }` (i.e. no `= {`).  It first passes compilation because Scala allows a value to be discarded when `Unit` is expected (that behavior can be made a warning with the compiler option `-Ywarn-value-discard`).  You can solve this by being explicit that you want this method to be called for value by including the `=`.

```scala
override def testComponent(input: java.util.Map[String, Object], metadata: java.util.Map[String, Object]) = {
  val list: util.List[Map[String, AnyRef]] = new util.ArrayList[Map[String, AnyRef]]
  list  // return should be avoided in Scala: it's not necessary and can introduce some really subtle bugs
}
```

It's generally a good idea to be explicit about the result type of a public method.  Alternatively, this should also work:

```scala
override def testComponent(input: java.util.Map[String, Object], metadata: java.util.Map[String, Object]) =
  new ArrayList[Map[String, AnyRef]]
```